# VS2019 Custom template not shown

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I have created a custom template for VS2019 that contains two projects. Below is my root.vstemplate file

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Asp.Net Core Template EF Core</Name>
    <Description>Asp.Net Core 3.1 Boilerplate template</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>Asp.Net Core Template EF Core</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>logo.png</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="AspNet Core Ef Core">
        src\AspNetCore3EfCoreTemplate\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="AspNet Core Ef Core Web">
        src\AspNetCore3EfCoreTemplate.Web\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I followed the instructions of this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019) but my template is not shown when I try to create a new item in VS2019. Anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: For the custom project template, the new VS2019 UI for creating projects cannot find custom templates through filters and they actually are exists in it. This behavior is a known issue. Please clear the filter and then you can find your new template near the end of all templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I followed the instructions of this link but my template is not shown
>   when I try to create a new item in VS2019. Anyone knows why is this
>   happening?

For the custom project template, the new VS2019 UI for creating projects cannot find custom project templates through filters and these templates actually exist in it.

`All Langages`, `All Platforms` and `All Project Types` and the search box lose the ability to filter custom project templates and this is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/422666/allow-custom-project-templates-for-custom-language.html) in VS2019. But it still happens in the latest version `VS2019 16.4.2`. If you want to solve this annoying problem, you can report an issue to [DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report this abnormal behavior for support. This might be a long process or you can try my suggestions below:

**Suggestion**

**1)** Do not use any filters in VS2019 Project UI and then drag to the bottom of all templates to find the custom template, which is usually inserted after all the default templates.

[image]

This picture shows it at the bottom of all templates.

**2)** change to use VS2017 which has no error about this.

**Update 1**

l have created with your further info and test in my side without any errors, my environment:

**win10 enterprise 1903**; **VS2019 Community 16.4.2**

**My Steps**:

**1)** l have created two projects into a same solution: 
a **Net Core 3.1 ClassLibrary project** and a **ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application project**.

**2)** then click Export Template.. in the **Project** menu and export these projects as **project template** separately.

**3)** open the folder and unzip them into the same folder called **src**.

This shows the two unzip project folders in the **src** folder

[image]

Then, this shows the final form of the folder,and src folder contains the two project folders as the picture shows above

[image]

**4)** `root.vstemplate` is the code you provide. The project Template is called `Asp.Net Core Template EF Core` as you said. After that, I compress these two files into a package called multiple projects template,and then put this zip file into this path `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates`.

**5)** then I close VS Instance and then restart VS and clear all the filters and then pull the project templates to the bottom, and then look up at the bottom for a template called `Asp.Net Core Template EF Core`.

**>** l have found this template in my side and if you does not see this, please [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and then disable any third-party extensions in the Extension-->Manage Extension menu to prevent interference with VS. Besides, since your VS is 16.4.1, you could try to update it to 16.4.2.

**Update 2**

With your sample, l think l found the issue. The issue is that root.template cannot find the two contained projects:

You put `root.template` in the `Src` folder and the `root.vstemplate` file write these:

```
src\ClassLibrary1\MyTemplate.vstemplate

src\WebApplication3\MyTemplate.vstemplate
```

It uses **relative** paths to find these files and the current path where your `root.vstemplate` is located does not have **src** so it cannot find.

The solution is that you should put `root.vstemplate`in the same directory as the **SRC** folder and then compress these two. After that, put this `Multiple.zip` into `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates`.

[image]

Hope it could help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested no filters nothing but still cannot see it there

Comment: When you put the `xxx.zip` file into `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates` and then restart your VS, and you can find it near the bottom of the all templates. l just do this, and it actually there.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing but it is not there. I can send you the template if you wish. just send me an email

Comment: I tried that and I can see it. That does not answer though what is the problem with my template which is the initial question of this post

Comment: What is your VS2019 version and what type of the project you include into the template?

Comment: v16.4.1. The template consists of two projects. (.NET Core 3.1 class library and asp.net core 3.1)

Comment: Thanks for you sharing the info and l will check and share my steps for you next Monday. Please wait patiently. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I can send you the template to check if you want.

Comment: Did my answer help you  understand the steps about that? If follow my steps and also face the same issue, l think the issue is related to VS Environment, and my steps did not help you, you can try to reinstall VS.

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering you. I was away. Can you please share root.vstemplate file contents?

Comment: Sorry  for replying you so late. I just use the `root.vstemplate` which you provided and do not do any changes. If you still face this problem, l think the issue is related to VS IDE. You could try to reinstall VS or disable any third party extensions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Is it possible to send me your template to test it here?

Comment: Sorry to tell you that we cannot provide your such sample and this may cause inconvenience. What l have done is just listed on above. And l do not do any changes in the project `Net Core 3.1 ClassLibrary project` and  `ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application project` and use your `root.template` without any changes.  Speak clearly, l suggest you can try to test this in another PC to test whether it is the issue of your PC's environment.

Comment: I have updated VS2019 to v16.4.3 and still the same problem occurs. Please find attached the exported template https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QVB2na5FEyPBY_p42f6WDKOHcoSw9eQQ/view?usp=sharing and try to open it on your machine and let me know if that works for you

Comment: l think the issue  is that you should put `root.vstemplate` file  in the same directory as the `SRC` folder. With this change, l can see the Multiple template in my side. Please see Update two.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue. Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2019 uses tags to filter projects. By default when you export a project template, the `.vstemplate` file doesn't contain the required tags. You need to edit the `.vstemplate` file and add the following tags in the `TemplateData` section (I.e. between `<TemplateData>` and `</TemplateData>`) and replace the values with the appropriate values for your template:

```
<LanguageTag>Language</LanguageTag>
<PlatformTag>Platform</PlatformTag>
<ProjectTypeTag>Type</ProjectTypeTag>
```

For example, here is the `TemplateData` for one of my custom templates:

```
<TemplateData>
  <Name>MyCaliburnMicroTemplate</Name>
  <Description>Caliburn Micro template I set up with basic localisation, logging, settings and themes implemented.</Description>
  <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  <ProjectSubType>Windows</ProjectSubType>
  <LanguageTag>CSharp</LanguageTag>
  <PlatformTag>Windows</PlatformTag>
  <ProjectTypeTag>Desktop</ProjectTypeTag>
  <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
  <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
  <DefaultName>MyCaliburnMicroTemplate</DefaultName>
  <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
  <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
  <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
  <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
</TemplateData>
```

I also set the `<ProjectSubType>` to Windows, but I haven't tested to see if this makes any difference.

Here's a picture of my 'Create a new project' window with the filters set to C#, Windows and Desktop:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 - Create a new project window]

Notice the tags now appear below the description of my project template. I'm currently using Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.4.3, but haven't tested this with any other version.

Comment: This worked for me - adding these tags allowed the template to show with the language, platform and project type filters selected, although not with the search when searching for the name of the template

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to make it work:
After the zip file of the template was created, I extracted it.
Then I copied the folder to the "ProjectTamplates" folder.

I was able to create a new project based on my template this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
https://blog.jayway.com/2015/03/13/visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects/

The original documentation usually miss a step or 2 that looks obvious after you made a lots of templates.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same issue, that my project does not apper in search window of projects in VS.

In folder "ProjectTemplates" I had zip that was containing dots in name. After removing them my project appeared in projects window in VS.

I hope this will help someone.